# Is it feasible to ditch CocoaPods after issuing `pod install` in iOS app?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I already executed `pod install` in my iOS app, but how can I ditch the whole cocoapods control and revert back to the state where my app didn't use cocodapods at all? Here's what I have done:

Create the following file named `Podfile` and run `pod install`

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'SVProgressHUD'
```

However, I later realized I shall not use the package, so now I want to revert it back to the previous state. Just deleting the Pod-related files and directories didn't make it...

So is it still feasible to revert back? Or do I have to create my App from the point of creating a new project?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no automatic function that I know, but it can be easily done manually.

1. Remove `Pods` folder near your `Podfile`
2. Remove next files: `Podfile` and `Podfile.lock`
3. Remove generated `<Project_Name>.workspace` file
4. Open your `xcodeproj` file and in `Xcode`:

   - Remove reference to `Pods-<YOUR_TARGET>.xcconfig` file at the end of root folder [image]
   - Open project setting and choose `Build Phases` tab in your target setting:
     Remove here two phases: `Check Pods Manifest.lock` and `Copy Pods Resources`[image][image]
   - Open 'Build Phases' - > `Link Binary With Libraries` and remove all links that starts from `libPods...` [image]
   - Switch to project settings  and deselect (must be `None` everywhere if you haven't created before) configuration sets if there are any at `Info` tab.[image]

Comment: Thanks. In fact I completed step 1 ~ 3 before posting the question, but still got a lot of errors and leaned on this site with quite an anxiety. Your solution acted like a magic - thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

#### Self Answer

While the answer by @Ossir works properly, I have found one library called [cocoapods-deintegrate](https://github.com/kylef/cocoapods-deintegrate) that takes charge of all the work that deintegrate CocoaPods from your project.

In order to use it, you first install it by `gem install cocoapods-deintegrate` (*sudo* might be required) and then just `pod deintegrate` from your project root. It still leaves *Podfile*, *Podfile.lock*, and *.xcworkspace/*.